# How can i make this work with all subdomains?

Tags: php

If I have the function below, how can I make it work with 2 or more subdomains?

the root domain has several subdomains like subdomain.example.com and subdomains2.example.com but I want this code to work with these 2 subdomains only, how could I do that?

```
function denyNonOther($url)
{
    $strAllow = 'subdomain.example.com'; 
    $strBase  = getBaseUrl($url);
    if(strpos($url, $strAllow) === false)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: include some more details in question

Comment: the root domain has several subdomains like subdomain.example.com and subdomains2.example.com but i want this code to work with these 2 subdomains only, how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a file and include it in your main domain and others subdomain .

Comment: the root domain has several subdomains like subdomain.example.com and subdomains2.example.com but i want this code to work with these 2 subdomains only, how could i do that?

Comment: @MichaelJS when you access a subdomain u are actually access a php file, you should to include this function on that file.